# R: Pam function under cluster package not accepting data set having more than 65536 entries

Tags: r, clustering

I am running pam function for kmedoid under cluster package in R. My dataset has 1 million entries.
It's throwing error  saying

> Have 1 million observation but not more than 65536 observation allowed

Please suggest the solution

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If you read the package [News section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/news.html) you will find:

> pam() now signals an error when there are more than 65536 observational units (whereas it could segfault previously), thanks to a patch from Mikko Korpela, Helsinki.

So it seems there isn't a solution.

Comment: Looks like they're only using 16-bit integers to store dataset size. Oof.